# Include a picture in Visual Studio 2013 Template

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to include a picture into my Visual Studio 2013 Template. I see that the picture is added to the .zip file, but it is not created when I use the template for a new solution.

```
    <Project TargetFileName="OpenCV Template1.vcxproj" File="OpenCV Template1.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">OpenCV Template1.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="Test.cpp">Test.cpp</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="OpenCVLogo.jpg">OpenCVLogo.jpg</ProjectItem>
</Project>
```

How can I tell Visual Studio to include the Logo.jpg when I create a new solution?